# DataBricks PySpark withColumn() Fails After First Success

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I'm working in DataBricks with Python/PySpark.  I have several output columns that copy a single input column.  One of the output columns is the lower-case version of the upper-case or mixed-case input column, which I need to rename this way before I drop it.  Because I am also casting its type, I use the `withColumn()` command (rather than the `withColumnRenamed()` command).

This works fine the first time but fails afterward.  DataBricks/PySpark is a case-sensitive language, so this should work.  What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

DataBricks/PySpark is, indeed, a case-sensitive language, but using the `withColumn()` command this way - to re-cast and re-name an existing column from upper/mixed-case to lower-case (or any combination of case-change that does not also change the actual column name) - causes the `withColumn()` command to revert to a `withColumnRenamed()` outcome, such that the input column remains afterward (a lower-case duplicate is not created) but is simply renamed/re-cast.

All subsequent calls to use the original upper/mixed-case column name will fail because it no longer exists.  For example:

```
df = df \
    .withColumn("new_lower_case_column_name", col("Mixed_Case_Column_Name").cast(SomeType()) \  # SUCCESS
    .withColumn("mixed_case_column_name", col("Mixed_Case_Column_Name").cast(SomeType()) \  # SUCCESS
    .withColumn("new_additional_lower_case_column_name", col("Mixed_Case_Column_Name").cast(SomeType()) \  # FAIL
```

At output, `df.columns` contains `"mixed_case_column_name"` and `"new_lower_case_column_name"` but does not contain `"new_additional_lower_case_column_name"`.

Many solutions will resolve this issue, including saving the case-change-name call for last, using the case-change-name for all subsequent calls, or use of a nomenclature (naming convention) that ensures the changed case name will differ from its original (e.g., using a prefix/suffix), and etc....